# How to keep track of previous value of variable in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift5

I am trying keep track of previously selected row index of tableview inside sideMenu.

Comment: Use one variable to keep track of selected index of tableView. This is can be done in didselect method

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and reliable solution. Use the [`willSet`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) property observer to keep track of the previous value of a variable.

```
var previousSelectedIndex: IndexPath?
var selectedIndex: IndexPath? {
    willSet {
        previousValue = selectedIndex
    }
}
```

Use the `selectedIndex` variable to keep track of the current selected index which you can get from your `didSelect` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousSelectedIndex = 0
var currentSelectedIndex = 0 {
didSet {
    print("===>current", currentSelectedIndex)
    print("===>previous", previousSelectedIndex)
}
willSet {
   previousSelectedIndex = self.currentSelectedIndex
}
```

explanation: didSet and willSet is property Observer in swift 
didset is use to get current value of variable and will set is use to get previous value of variable .
IF you want to learn more detail about propertyObserver refer this link
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/property-observers-didset-and-willset-in-swift-4-c3730f26b1e9

Comment: provide some explanation for your answer.